# Is it possible to put a function inside a function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, modal-dialog

So i have this function that i need to disable the button in my modal when the input is empty by using this.

```
 canBeSubmitted() {
      const { Department, Employee_Name, Address } = this.state;
      return (
        Department.length > 0 &&
        Employee_Name.length > 0 &&
        Address.length > 0 
      );
}
```

but when the modal is already clicked I assigned it to be empty but the button is enable again which it's supposed to be disabled

```
handleSubmit(name, address,department){

 const laman = {
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail?', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(laman)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)

      return response.json();
    })
    .then((result)=> {     
     var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
     jsonReturnedValue.push(result);
     this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
//this is where i call the function but it doesnt work
         this.canBeSubmitted()
           this.refs.Name.value="";
           this.refs.Address.value="";
           this.refs.Department.value="";
           // this.setState({ value: '' });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);

        })
```

And this is my button

```
  <input type="button" className="btn btn-info"disabled={!isEnabled} 
                        onClick = { this.handleSubmit.bind(
                                    this, this.state.Employee_Name,
                                    this.state.Address,
                                    this.state.Department)
                                     }
                                   value =" Add Employee"
                                   data-dismiss="modal"/>
```

Comment: so what should i do then?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the button does not disable is that you are not toggling the **isEnabled** variable used in your html.
My suggestion would be as follows: 
In the constructor of your class

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.setState({
  isEnabled: false
});
}
```

Now you have initialized a default value in the constructor.

Now in the success clause of your promise use the following code :

```
.
.
.
this.canBeSubmitted()
this.refs.Name.value="";
this.refs.Address.value="";
this.refs.Department.value="";
this.setState({
 isEnabled: true
});
```

and set the state back to false in your error clause

```
.catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
          this.setState({
           isEnabled: false          
          });

    })
```

and now change your html to the following:

```
    render(){
    .
    .
    let {isEnabled} = this.state;
    return (
    <input type="button" className="btn btn-info" disabled={isEnabled} 
                                onClick = { this.handleSubmit.bind(
                                            this, this.state.Employee_Name,
                                            this.state.Address,
                                            this.state.Department)
                                             }
                                           value =" Add Employee"
                                           data-dismiss="modal"/>

    );
}
```

And write a new method which should be called on *closing* the modal and set the state value of *isEnabled* back to *false*

Comment: Have you written a method which is called on closing the modal?